# Google column chart with a dynamic column count

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization, dynamic-arrays

I have successfully coded several stacked column charts with no problem, all having a similar structure shown in the snippet below:

```
arr.push(['Date', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4', 'Item5']);
for (let i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
{
    arr.push
    (
        [
            jsonData[i].date,
            Number(jsonData[i].item1),
            Number(jsonData[i].item2),
            Number(jsonData[i].item3),
            Number(jsonData[i].item4),
            Number(jsonData[i].item5)
        ]
    );
}
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
```

When I execute the above code, I get several stacked columns (by date) where each column is comprised of several stacks representing the values associated with item1-item5 in the array. The item count is fixed and I know the name of each item to be displayed in the legend in advance (i.e. the chart has a legend showing "Item1", "Item2", ..., "Item5" as defined in my initial arr.push statement. All good...

Now I am trying to do something seemingly very similar however I do not know in advance the number or names of different items comprising any one stacked column. The items are being read from a database and for one column there may be only one "stack" item and for another there may be 5 "stack" items. In practice, what I'm trying to do is chronologically chart medical claims by medical provider where I do not know the names or number of medical providers in advance. Each column will be comprised of medical claims filed that month-year with color-coded "stacks" mapping to a specific medical provider (whose names will show in the legend).

The only way I can see to do what I want would be to first query the database to return a list of all DISTINCT medical providers and then supply that list of names as columns in the array (many of which will have a claim count of zero). As this seems very brute force, I suspect there's a better way...

Thanks in advance for any-and-all assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically construct the header array based on all unique providers and populate the data rows by mapping these providers to their respective claim counts for each date.

```js
// Create a set to store all unique medical providers, and an array to store the formatted data
let uniqueProviders = new Set();
let formattedData = [];

// Loop through your JSON data to populate 'uniqueProviders' and initialize 'formattedData'
jsonData.forEach(record => {
  uniqueProviders.add(record.provider);
  if (!formattedData.some(entry => entry.date === record.date)) {
    formattedData.push({ date: record.date, claims: {} });
  }
  let dateEntry = formattedData.find(entry => entry.date === record.date);
  dateEntry.claims[record.provider] = record.claimCount;
});

// Convert 'uniqueProviders' to an array and sort it, then create the header
let sortedProviders = Array.from(uniqueProviders).sort();
let header = ['Date', ...sortedProviders];

// Create an array to hold your Google Charts data, starting with the header
let arr = [header];

// Populate 'arr' with the data for each date
formattedData.forEach(record => {
  let row = [record.date];
  sortedProviders.forEach(provider => {
    row.push(record.claims[provider] || 0);
  });
  arr.push(row);
});

// Create the Google Chart data object
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
```

I've added comments throughout showing the steps to extract unique providers, initialize a formatted data structure, and then fill in this structure. Finally, it constructs the `arrayToDataTable` as required by Google Charts.

Comment: suchislife - Awesome approach that never occurred to me - works perfectly - thanks!

Comment: Feel free to accept & Keep on codin'!